# Microtime() Equivalent for C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, microtime

I am wondering if there is an equivalent to the PHP function microtime() in C **and** C++.  I looked around but couldn't find a definitive answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux, you can use [gettimeofday](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday), which should give the same information.  In fact, I believe that is the function that PHP uses under the covers.

Comment: and in C++11 you can [std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55553669/1067003)

Answer (score 9):

There is no exact equivalent to PHP's microtime(), but you could a function with a similar functionality based on the following code:

#### Mac OS X and probably also Linux/Unix

```
#include <sys/time.h>
struct timeval time;
gettimeofday(&time, NULL); #This actually returns a struct that has microsecond precision.
long microsec = ((unsigned long long)time.tv_sec * 1000000) + time.tv_usec;
```

(based on: http://brian.pontarelli.com/2009/01/05/getting-the-current-system-time-in-milliseconds-with-c/)

---

#### Windows:

```
unsigned __int64 freq;
QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER*)&freq);
double timerFrequency = (1.0/freq);

unsigned __int64 startTime;
QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&startTime);

//do something...

unsigned __int64 endTime;
QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&endTime);
double timeDifferenceInMilliseconds = ((endTime-startTime) * timerFrequency);
```

(answer by Darcara, from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4568649/330067)

Comment: it's `struct timeval time;`

Comment: Note for Windows users: You have to include profileapi.h (#include <profileapi.h>).

Comment: actually i disagree, as of C++11 there is [an exact equivalent to PHP's microtime()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55553669/1067003) - still, your answer may be the way to get it in C :)

Comment: Could someone explain the casts in the last row of the first example? I understand that it casts `time.tv_sec` to `unsigned long long` which will become the resulting type of the multiplication and also the addition. Then this gets assigned (and cast) into a `long` on the left. What is the idea here?

Answer (score 4):

C++11 added some standard timekeeping functions (see section 20.11 "Time utilities") with good accuracy, but most compilers don't support those yet.

Mostly you need to use your OS API, such as `gettimeofday` for POSIX.

Answer (score 4):

in c++11 i believe the equivalent to php's `microtime(true)` is:

```
#include <chrono>
double microtime(){
    return (double(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count()) / double(1000000));
}
```

- but i'm not sure what the C equivalent is, or if there even is one (as others have pointed out, gettimeofday is part of posix, but not part of c/c++ specs)

interestingly a microsecond is one millionth of a second, but c++ also supports nanoseconds, which is one BILLIONTH of a second, i guess you'd get higher precision with `std::chrono::nanoseconds` instead of `std::chrono::microseconds`, but at that point you'd probably run into max number limits of `double`, and the function name would be misleading (such a function should have the name `nanotime()` not `microtime()`, and the return should probably be something bigger than double), btw i have a collection of php-functions-ported-to-c++ here: https://github.com/divinity76/phpcpp (and microtime() is among them)

Answer (score 3):

For timing sections of code, try [std::clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/), which returns ticks, then divide by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Comment: I guess it depends on the platform: not necessarily on Windows, but other implementations should be XSI-compliant (CLOCKS_PER_SEC == 1000000)

Comment: It's also not real time but cpu time.

Comment: It also isn't an absolute timestamp (calendar), but simply elapsed time.

Answer (score 1):

libUTP (uTorrent Transport Protocol library) has a good [example](https://github.com/bittorrent/libutp/blob/master/utp_utils.cpp) on getting the microtime on different platforms.